# Download Pipeline Artifacts task goes above 100% for a 2+ Gb artifact

Tags: azure-devops

An Azure Pipeline has two stages - one has jobs which publish artifacts using `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` task. Artifacts range in size from 50MB to 2GB.

The second stage has a bunch of jobs which download individual artifacts using `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2` task. This works fine for smaller ones. For those around 2GBs in size the download task does not stop at 100% and keeps showing progress above 100% mark continuing downloading ... until the Azure DevOps agent runs out of disk space and the pipeline fails.

The behaviour is repeatable but strangely enough there was only mention of a similar issue without any hints to a possible solution.

Can somebody at least suggest what to try? Thanks

Comment: How about the result when you test it on your private agent? It seems to be a limitation of azure pipeline.

Comment: MS Hosted agents use `Standard_DS2_v2` which have 14 GB temp storage. More info [here]. I rather doubt that this is an issue with space available and it is rather limitation of azure pipelines like @LeoLiu-MSFT mentioned. You can create isssue on developer community to raise and idea of changing that limitation.